# Google Places APIs for my iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

I am developing an iPhone application in which I am using Google Places APIs. I am finding user's current location using GPS. And I want to display places around user's current location. I am able to find places around users but in JSON data which is returned by Google APIs do not include images of places.

How can I get images of places using Google places APIs?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

check this cool project built for exactly the same reason - [iOS5-Google-Places](https://github.com/jdruid/Google-Places-for-iOS-5). More [here as a blog post](http://drew5.net/2011/11/28/google-places-for-ios-5-sdk/). It also has has search built in.

> Application will determine location.  Issue Google Places API request
>   containing the LAT and LNG and TYPES (types are configurable) and will
>   return JSON results into an object to display in UITableView.

This should solve your requirements.

Just in case this is not baking your cake, then you need to roll up your own iOS Google Places wrapper using a `UIWebView` and [Google Places APIs](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/).